# How to supply the GCM authentication tag to the OpenSSL command line tools?

Tags: authenticated-encryption, gcm, openssl

I'm using AES-256-GCM for authenticated encryption. In order to decrypt, the [ruby OpenSSL library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL.html) requires an `auth_tag` parameter (in addition to the key and iv). This, according to the [ruby docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html#label-Authenticated+Encryption+and+Associated+Data+%28AEAD%29), is because authenticated encryption is only supported with associated data (AEAD).

How can I use this `auth_tag` to decrypt? The [node.js crypto library](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) doesn't have an option for it, so I'm trying to use the [openssl command line tool](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/openssl.html). However, looking at the [docs](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/enc.html), even that doesn't have an option for supplying the authetication tag.

Comment: The `auth_tag` parameter actually has nothing to do with associated data; that's what the (confusingly similar-named) `auth_data` parameter is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's a NodeJS AES-GCM module](https://github.com/xorbit/node-aes-gcm). Or alternatively, you can use the OpenSSL library to write your own GCM decryption code, [here's a quick tutorial](http://incog-izick.blogspot.fr/2011_08_01_archive.html).

The OpenSSL utility has [historically not supported](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/id-aes256-GCM-command-line-encrypt-decrypt-fail-td27187.html) GCM encryption/decryption via command line parameters, likely due to the auth tag issue. I don't think that anything has changed since then, so you may want to take another approach.

Comment: Thanks. If the utility doesn't support it, I'd rather just MAC my AES-CBC ciphertext, rather than use GCM.